# Elegant way for keeping the previous item accessible in a loop through items of a list

Tags: python, loops, pyflakes

**Summary:**

In a Python Project I need to apply a function to each two elements of a list of lists that have the same inner index and a neighbouring outer index.
The outputs get stored in a new matrix.

The code I've written works, but is not elegant and pyflakes complains about it.

How do I clean up this code?

**Additional Info:**

The code I'm writing is part of a module that solves a number puzzle.

At one point I am looping through a list of lists of class-instances.
They represent cells in rows in a playing field.
And I need to apply a function to each two vertically neighbouring cells,
and store its output in a new matrix.

Here it doesn't matter which of the cells in a pair is first, but the pairs need to be in order.

**Code excerpt:**

```py
def func(cell_matrix):
    out_matrix = []
    for y_pos, line in enumerate(cell_matrix):
        out_line = []
        if y_pos != 0:
            for x_pos, cell in enumerate(line):
                out_line.append(compare_func(prev_line[x_pos], cell)
            out_matrix.append(out_line)
        prev_line = line
    return out_matrix
```

**What pyflakes complains about:**

```
Line 7: pyflakes [E]: undefined name 'prev_line'
Line 9: pyflakes [E]: local variable 'prev_line' is assigned to but never used
```

Comment: I think it would be solved if you define `prev_line=None` below `out_matrix = []`

Comment: no, will still be prev_line[x_pos] will have nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to use only indexes, thus you spare the prev_ variable.

E.g.

```
def func(cell_matrix):                                                           
    out_matrix = []                                                              
    for y_pos in range(len(cell_matrix)):                                        
        out_line = []                                                            
        if y_pos != 0:                                                           
            for x_pos in range(len(cell_matrix[y_pos])):                         
                out_line.append(compare_func(cell_matrix[y_pos-1][x_pos],        
                                             cell_matrix[y_pos][x_pos]))         
            out_matrix.append(out_line)                                          
    return out_matrix
```

But it could be even more simplified by using a comprehension:

```
def func(cell_matrix):                                                           
    return [[compare_func(                                                       
                 cell_matrix[y_pos-1][x_pos], cell_matrix[y_pos][x_pos])         
             for x_pos in range(len(cell_matrix[y_pos]))]                        
            for y_pos in range(1, len(cell_matrix))]
```

Edit:
By the way, the errors you get are pyflakes messages, the code runs fine afaik. (One could argue it's pyflakes' inability to parse the code correctly)

Comment: isn't it discouraged to iterate through elements of a list by using len(list)?
Looks sound otherwise though.

Comment: correct, I heard this too. But the only alternative I came around was
```for y_pos, _unused in enumerate(cell_matrix):```
Not sure I like it.

Comment: So functionally this is exactly where I needed to be pointed.
It lacks a bit in readability, that's why I put my own answer below, but I'm going to accept yours.
Btw I understand that pyflakes' complaining doesn't mean my code wouldn't work, but preceived it as another sign of my code being clumsy.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the variable name before you use it:

```
def func(cell_matrix):
    out_matrix = []
    prev_line = cell_matrix[0]    # use 1st line as prev_line
    for line in cell_matrix[1:]:  # use 2nd to nth line, no y_pos used
                                  # in the following code so no need to enumerate
        out_line = []
            for x_pos, cell in enumerate(line):
                out_line.append(compare_func(prev_line[x_pos], cell) ) # missing )
            out_matrix.append(out_line)
        prev_line = line
    return out_matrix
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to:

```py
def func(cell_matrix):
    out_matrix = []
    prev_line = []
    for y_pos, line in enumerate(cell_matrix):
        out_line = []
        if y_pos != 0:
            for x_pos, cell in enumerate(line):
                out_line.append(compare_func(prev_line[x_pos], cell)
            out_matrix.append(out_line)
        prev_line = line
    return out_matrix
```

You need to declare `prev_line` out of the for loop scope so it can use it every loop.

Comment: very first pass through this code, this line: `out_line.append(compare_func(prev_line[x_pos], cell)` will try to access `None[x_pos]`

Comment: It won't. In the first pass that line is not executed because the if-statement prevents it. Then prev_line gets overwritten with line.

Comment: It executes just as well, but now pylint outputs this error:
`[E1136] 8 : func: Value 'prev_line' is unsubscriptable`

Comment: @fatalcreator changed prev_line = [ ], try it too, I edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

I ended up moving the iterating to a seperate function because I find it easier to read this way.

```py
def subsequences(var, r=2):
    """Yield subsequences of var with length r"""
    # subsequences("ABCD") --> AB BC CD
    for index in range(len(var)-r+1):
        yield tuple(var[index+n] for n in range(r))

def func(cell_matrix):
    return [
        [
            compare_func(cell_a, cell_b)
            for cell_a, cell_b in zip(prev_line, line)
        ]
        for prev_line, line in subsequences(cell_matrix)
    ]
```

It might just be personal taste though.